# Excel formula - copy to cell if multiple conditions are met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create this formula in excel 2019.

I am trying to achieve the following, in my yearly budgeting riport. I do not want to manually move the financial data, by months, categories and priority. I want to copy from one page to another page (my extract) into the corresponding months, category the data fits into.

In short: I want a cell on page 1 to be equal with another if three conditions are met. The first condition is a date in column 1. If it's between 01.-01.31. then yes copy if not no. Next, if its category fuel yes copy if not no. The third is if its 1 copy yes if its 2 not.

Thanks in advance for your help

[This is where I want to copy the data to broken up by months](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMDVm.jpg)

[This is the data I want to sum and copy if conditions are met.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtiKA.jpg)

1. First condition: Yellow column is a range of dates by months (ex. if its in january)
2. Second condition: green is the cost category (and its car leasing)
3. Third condition: red is another category (and is one)

copy the data in black column (sry sensitive data) to sheet one and sum it with the rest.

black is the costs that I want to copy then sum it

Comment: You need to provide a data sample in order for us to help you. Perhaps try to show us the columns that the conditions should be based on?

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your help i will provide screenshots of the 2 pages and the data i want to copy if conditions are met. We use the hungarian version of excel. Thank you so much